# HTML5 Nav Bar not sticky over floating objects

Tags: html, css-float, sticky

I got my navigation bar styled like this:

```
ul#navigation {
    font-size: 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #824c71;
    position: sticky; /*<-!*/
    top: 0;
}
```

And now, I got several floating elements on my page, styled like this one:

```
<div style="width:50%;background-color:#e6c79c;margin:3%;float:left;padding:1em;">
```

and next to it (since it is floating left) this one:

```
<div style="width:flex;background-color:#e6c79c;margin:3%;float:right;padding:2em;padding-top:1em;text-align:center;position:sticky;">
```

What I attempted was to have
 1. a sticky navigation bar that stays sticky when scrolling over a floating div element. With my setup it is sticky until it touches a floating element.
 2. two sticky elements on the same page. The second element, which is floating right, shall stick to the navigation bar when scrolling (maybe in a safety distance of 1em :))

It would be great if anyone can help me to see my error. Thanks in advance, cheers!

Edit: I'm doing this for a project where only HTML and CSS is allowed.. don't ask..

Answer (score 0):

If you want he navbar to always stay 'sticky' use the css property display: fixed; instead of sticky. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) is a link that shows the differences between display propertys. Position sticky switches between fixed and relative depending on the scroll position. Fixed will keep the navbar at the top all the time and you can use the top, bottom, left, right properties to place the fixed navbar where you want it on the page.